# Getting Dropdown CheckBoxList values using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, devexpress

I've got a `ListBox` inside a `DropDownEdit`.

Now I need to get selected values using javascript. The problem is seeing multiple instances of both in debugger, so I don't undestand how to get values I need.

My `ASP.NET` and `javascript` code: https://jsfiddle.net/dgaxvxnz/

Google Chrome Debugger shows these inputs:
http://textuploader.com/dslkh

Since my reputation is below 10, I can't post more than 2 links, so I linked DevExpress source code, I took as sample, in Debugger output above.

Comment: As far I saw, DevExpress has they own javascript libraries to help you dealing with this situation, right? This may help you https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q323183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. To get chosen options I took `dde_ResourceGroup_DDD_lbx_ResourceGroup_0_VI` value, which is something like this: `"1|21|41|51|62|13"`. Of course, it had to be parsed. So, the chosen values are: `2, 4, 5, 6, 13`. I still wonder, why it has `1` or `2` at the beginning and after each symbol but last and what does it depend on.